# Asymmetric top eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I read that for a symmetric top (oblate or prolate) we can find the exact eigenfunctions (in terms of Winger matrices) and eigenstates, but we can't do it in general for an asymmetric top. I am not sure I understand why. The Hamiltonian for an asymmetric top, for a given J, can be written in terms of $J^2, J_z, J^+$ and $J^−$ (where the operators are in the intrinsic frame). So for a given J, we can build the Hamiltonian ($(2J+1) \times (2J+1)$ matrix), which will mix different values of K. But we can diagonalize this Hamiltonian (which is initially in the basis of the symmetric top wavefunction), and from there extract the energies and eigenfunctions (which will be linear combinations of the symmetric top wavefunction). Why is this not true in general? Can't we always get the eigenfunctions of an asymmetric top in this way? Thank you!